# Run a PHP script when RSS feed updates (cron jobs?)

Tags: php, iphone, rss, cron, apple-push-notifications

I have a script that sends out a push notification to users based on whats in a PHP file. 
This is that file ...the parts that matter ...

```
   $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->load('RandomXML Url location here ');
  $arrFeeds = array();
  foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $itemRSS = array ( 
      'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
      'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
      'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
      'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue
      );
    array_push($arrFeeds, $itemRSS);
  }
// APPLE APNS EXAMPLE 1
$apns->newMessage(2);
$apns->addMessageAlert($itemRSS['title']);
// $apns->addMessageCustom('acme2', array('bang', 'whiz'));
$apns->queueMessage();
// SEND ALL MESSAGES NOW
$apns->processQueue();
```

So thats the PHP that sends out the notification. It sends out the notification when this PHP script is loaded.

It loads the first post from the feed and sends it out. I want to send a notification out every time the RSS feed is updated with a new post. If it is updated with a new feed, then I want to run the above code.

So how can I do that and make sure it is run frequently?

I would really like to see what code I need to check if its updated? I don't know how to check for updates though and thats probably the most important part of the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure Cron to run your script every e.g. 1 hour and in script add code to check is RSS modified.

EDIT:
1. You can configure Cron to run your script every e.g. 1 hour.
2. To the script, add the code to test whether the RSS has been modified.
3. To check whether the feed was changed use the  tag. You can save the  tag content to txt and compare it.
4. To write  tag content you can use [SimpleXML](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) and [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).

Comment: Any idea what code I would need to see if the RSS has changed?

Comment: Store the GUIDs for each item in a database. When you encounter one you've never seen, it's new.

Comment: check if the pubDate is greater than?

Comment: the one I stored in the database , (sorry I kept pressing enter)

Comment: then if it is run the php script to send the notification.

Comment: You can also save <pubDate> tag content in txt and compare it every 1 hour.

Comment: Also. The RSS script is getting the last post in the XML, not the first post. How can I change that?

Comment: 1st question: You can use a SimpleXML: http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php (and fwrite to save it to txt). 2nd question: I don't know. :P